# JS: Audio plays on first load, but not on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, audio

The audio does play on the first load, but on page refresh I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Html:

```
     <div>
        <audio src="./songs/the_end.mp3" id="theEnd"></audio>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    const theEnd = document.querySelector('#theEnd')

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        theEnd.play()
    })
```

What should I change so that the audio plays even on page refresh just like it did on first load?

Codesandbox for you guys to test : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-brook-l06u8

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add `autoplay` attribute.

So:

```
 <div>
    <audio autoplay src="./songs/the_end.mp3" id="theEnd"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: if I do that the error goes away, but the audio still doesn't play on refresh

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Btw, `window.onload`-event doesn't work in that sandbox, you've provided at all.

Comment: Google chrome, yeah i didnt know the sandbox wouldnt work with window.onload either.